# How to add a string.Empty choice in a dropdownFor model in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a drop-down which display a list of items from database, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentID, "ParentID")
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ParentID", null,"Select Item")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentID, "")
            </div>
        </div>
```

I use ViewBag to transfer the list, and this is scaffold-it code (I delete the html object).

My model accept null values for this property, but I am not able to give it.

I need a way to insert a null option in the list, or to keep permanent the "Select Item". 
My problem exist only in the cases when I want to edit the object and select a null value for this property. This is not possible, because I do not have null value in list.

There is any possibility to insert a null option using drop-down properties?

Comment: Why can't you add a null value to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a collection of the `SelectListItem` items that you want in your dropdown and pass it as a second parameter to `DropDownListFor` method 
and for the 3rd parameter you need to put default ("empty") option label.

Please see an example below.

view code example:

```
@model ItemViewModel
@{
    List<ItemViewModel> items = ViewBag.Items ?? new List<ItemViewModel>();
    var selectListItems = items.Select(x => new SelectListItem() {Text = x.Name, Value = x.ParentID.ToString()});
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>DropDown example</h1>
    <p class="lead">dropdown with default value</p>
    <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID, selectListItems, "Select Item...")</p>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var items = new List<ItemViewModel>
            {
                new ItemViewModel {ParentID = 1, Name = "one"},
                new ItemViewModel {ParentID = 2, Name = "two"},
                new ItemViewModel {ParentID = 3, Name = "three"}
            };
            ViewBag.Items = items;
            var model = new ItemViewModel();
            //model.ParentId is null here
            return View(model);
```

model example:

```
public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

result:

[image: result - here we have a default value in dropdown]